# How can I do tuberculosis test for UK visa if I live in country where TB test is not required

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, health

I am from a country where TB test is required for UK Tier 2 General Visa.

I currently live in a country where TB test is not required, and I didnt find any information of where I can do that test at GOV.UK. Since that county is not listed so there are no "Approved test clinics" at website.

So the question is can I do the test in country where I live now, or should I back to my native country to do the test?

Answer (score 4):

You may be interpreting the policy incorrectly.  They do not care about your nationality, instead they care about where you are living...

> You’ll need to have a tuberculosis (TB) test if you’re coming to the
>   UK for more than 6 months and **are resident** in any of these listed
>   countries.

If you have lived in your current country legally for more than 6 months, then you are 'normally resident' there for the purposes of this policy.  So if a TB test is not required for where you are resident, then you're off the hook.

Comment: What if I am currently in a country where TB test is not required but I have travelled to a country where a TB test is required in the last 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no "Approved Test Clinics" listed for you country any tests you conduct in your country won't be accepted as valid by the UK immigration authorities.

If you look at the [List of Countries required to have TB test](https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa/countries-where-you-need-a-tb-test-to-enter-the-uk) there is actually a country suggestion where you can get tested since your country doesn't have an approved facility.

Comment: But there are "Approved Test Clinics" only for countries where TB test is required. So people, who live in countries where TB test is not required, have to go to a country where that TB test is required to do that test? Is it possible that I just not found where I can do that test at GOV.UK?

Comment: @angelovAlex That would be a good question to ask a local consulate or an embassy.

Comment: @angelovAlex From the gov.uk you need a TB test if you're a resident of: https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa/countries-where-you-need-a-tb-test-to-enter-the-uk  And there is actually a suggestion of the country to get tested at if yours doesn't have an approved facility.